# How do you build a state feedback controller for a linear system with more than one input?

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system

I have to design a feedback controller for a system where the $A$ matrix is $6 \times 6$ and the $B$ matrix is $2 \times 6$ ($2$ inputs). I've used Matlab to do it but I still need to write an explanation and I can't find any explanation or examples where system has more than one input.

Edit:
I have A and B and I have shown that they are controllable, I need to now design a matrix F (or K) to work as a feedback controller. The problem is that my textbook only shows how to do pole placement when B is a single column vector. I've already made the feedback control in Matlab and it works fine but I need to be able to show how I built the F matrix. I've also tried Ackermann's formula but my controllability matrix is 12x6 and can't be inverted.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: One way would be to design it so that is minimizes a criterion such as a quadratic criterion. Check what LQR is. Also, how did you design it with Matlab. Please add more details.